# How to pull one by one according to store with pdo

Tags: php, pdo

i have a problem. i try to creating photo gallery. i am saving photo and photo's name in database. Photo's name store named "baslik". Now, For example i am saving named "Winter Holiday", 10 photos. And i saved 2 photos named "Summer Holiday". When i pull the images and names, all photos and names are pulling. if i saved the photos named "Winter Holiday", other photos mustn't pull(Summer Holiday). It must pull one image from "Winter Holiday" and one image from "Summer Holiday".

```
<pre>
<?php
$resim = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cokluresimlistele WHERE baslik");
foreach($resim as $resimkoy) {
?>
<div class="resim">
<img src='upload/cokluresimlistele/<?php echo $resimkoy["cokluresimlistele_resim"]; ?>' />
<div class="resimyazisi"><a href='admin/panel/production/cokluresimlistele.php'><?php echo $resimkoy["baslik"]; ?></a></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `WHERE baslik` doesn't make sens without a condition. Do you mean `WHERE baslik = ?` ?

Comment: you need to use a where clause in your sql. see the linked answer for the PDO examples but first you need to refresh your knowledge on the raw SQL